# What platform to choose if I'm going to develop business web applications

Tags: web-applications

The main thing is that I have some ideas in my mind and we are teamed up with a friend of mine to write some killer web-based business apps. Well, this is enough for preliminary...

We were thinking about what platform to try out and use. The first idea was Java because we both know Java, and I've seen Spring in action so Spring MVC looked good. Then someone came to me and said "Hey Adobe Flex kicks *something* so use it for business apps." After reading Joel's little essay [Strategy Letter VI](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/09/18.html) it became obvious for me that Flash won't work in the long run (but correct me if I'm wrong) so what remains as far as I know are:

- Java with some fancy framework like Spring
- Python with Django
- (I mention Ruby and its Rails as a footnote though since it seems that the hype around it started to subside)

Well I had the idea to use LISP, albeit it seems the most powerful option around I can't name a single person who can program in LISP and only some of my programmer acquaintances have even heard about is. Same stands for libraries / frameworks we have to write from scratch if we use LISP.

So what do you think? Which will be the most efficient yet beneficial for a small team to use? Pros and cons?

I know there are some analogous questions out there but they seem localized to me and I think that finding a good platform for web-based business applications would be beneficial for others out there.

**Edit: I know there is the .NET platform but I don't really like the idea of using it...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that Clojure with Heroku will be our best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider [OpaLang](http://opalang.org/) and [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/); perhaps also [Kaya](http://kayalang.org/)

All are compiled frameworks, with focus on safety & reliability.

Comment: Regarding Lisp, there are a few companies using it extensively (and the same can be said for Ocaml or Haskell). I heard that during the Clinton area, the White House web server was in Common Lisp. Today, some company employ dozens of programmer in Common Lisp for a quite big project related to airline reservation (or something like that). Ocaml is used by several financial companies (Jane Street, Lexifi, ...)

Comment: Are they successful companies? By the way my main problem is that LISP programmers are few and far between so if my project expands it will be difficult to find a LISP programmer to help.

Comment: I don't know. I just happen to know a guy who was hired there (near Boston). And since I'm French & living near Paris, I don't have a good understanding about what successful small US companies are.